# Automatic JDBC Realm configuration

Tags: glassfish, file-descriptor, jdbcrealm

I want to know if it's possible to create JDBC Realm configuration in Glassfish 3.1 without admin console, like creation of a Data Source with the `glassfish-resources.xml`.
When developers download my GIT repository they don't like to configure Glassfish, it's configured in deployment time.

Best regards
Mounir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a shell script or batch file which runs the required `asadmin` commands.
Here you can find a complete example: [Creating JDBC Objects Using asadmin](http://blogs.oracle.com/lindstro/entry/creating_jdbc_options_from_the)

(Btw, [DTD](http://glassfish.java.net/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd) of [GlassFish Resources Descriptor](http://glassfish.java.net/dtds/) does not contain any realm-related tag (include `create-auth-realm`).)

Comment: Yeah it's seem the only solution to do this, but can I run this script at deployment time ?

Comment: AFAIK, just by hand. (I think that's fine. I wouldn't be happy if one of the applications silently reconfigure Glassfish during deployment.)