# Realm Configuration for Glassfish by Application like context in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, glassfish, java-ee-6, jdbcrealm

how to setup jdbc-realm security inside application by xml files. in tomcat we can use context.xml file to define realms but how can do it by glassfish similar glassfish-resources.xml for jdbc resources

RGDS

Comment: Related question: [Automatic JDBC Realm configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7852293/620338)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [GlassFish Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/glassfish/documentation/index.html) is your friend :-)

The JDBC Realm documentation is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2435/ggkuk.html#ggmww).