# Can we add security Realm to glassfish-resources

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, glassfish-4.1

Hi I am currently using JDBC realm in Glassfish 4.1.1 for authentication, and I wonder if I can add the configuration of jdbc realm to glassfish-resources.xml, so that when migrate, I can just call

```
 asadmin add-resources glassfish-resources.xml
```

to add all jdbc connection, datasources, and jdbcRealm to the new glassfish server?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot configure the security realm in glassfish-resouces.xml. See the [DTD](http://glassfish.java.net/dtds/glassfish-resources_1_5.dtd), there is no element for that. There is a feature request open for that, see [GLASSFISH-20874](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20874).

You can use a shellscript and the asadmin commands to do automatic configuration for all your resources or just for the security realm (`create-auth-realm`). Or use the REST-configuration interface.

Sources:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19546431/5658642
https://stackoverflow.com/a/7855104/5658642